# Cmdlet to round numbers in output

Tags: powershell

Is there a cmdlet that rounds numbers (all float values) in the output?

When I run the following command:

```
get-vm |select ProvisionedSpaceGB,UsedSpaceGB
```

I get this output as a table:

```
            ProvisionedSpaceGB                    UsedSpaceGB
            ------------------                    -----------
1224,0003194380551576614379883 349,88938544876873493194580078
1224,0003062393516302108764648 321,74483488313853740692138672
502,80292716529220342636108399 74,052481059916317462921142578
700,00035238638520240783691406 484,56624550372362136840820312
 800,0003144945949316024780273 322,26342210918664932250976562
```

I am aware that I can define that in the `select` cmdlet like this:

```
 get-vm | select @{ n="ProvisionedSpaceGB"; e={[math]::round( $_.ProvisionedSpaceGB, 2 )}},
    @{ n="UsedSpaceGB"; e={[math]::round( $_.UsedSpaceGB, 2 )}}
```

And then get this output:

```
ProvisionedSpaceGB UsedSpaceGB
------------------ -----------
           1224,00      349,58
           1224,00      320,32
            502,80       74,05
            700,00      484,57
            800,00      322,26
```

But there must be an easier way, like piping it into another cmdlet:

```
get-vm |select ProvisionedSpaceGB,UsedSpaceGB |RoundNumbers -Precision 2
```

To get the second output.

Comment: I don't think there is, but you can  create your own cmdlet for that...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I doubt there is a *built-in* PowerShell cmdlet for that, however - you could *write your own* filter:

```
filter Round-FloatValues
{
    Param(
        [parameter(ValueFromPipeline=$true)]
        $objects,

        [int]$Precision = 2        
    )

    $objects.PsObject.Properties | ForEach-Object {
        if ($_.TypeNameOfValue -eq 'System.Double')
        {
            [math]::round( $_.Value, $Precision )
        }
        else
        {
            $_.Value
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
get-vm |select ProvisionedSpaceGB,UsedSpaceGB |Round-FloatValues -Precision 2
```